# ansible-inventory --list host groups command line

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I would like to obtain the list of host group names (only) from ansible-inventory, however I'm having to use grep to trim down the list based on known group name patterns - e.g.

- Clean output but messy command line and need to know group name pattern ahead of time:

> `ansible-inventory -i inventory/production --list --yaml | grep webserver_.*:$`

- Clean command line and don't need to know group name pattern, but messy output:

> `ansible-playbook my-playbook.yml -i inventory/production --list-hosts`

Is there a clean way to extract just the group names from inventory?

Example hosts.yml:

```
# NGINX
webserver_1:
  hosts:
    ws1.public.example.com

webserver_2:
  hosts:
    ws2.public.example.com

webserver_2:
  hosts:
    ws2.public.example.com

# EC2 back-ends
backend_ec2_1:
  hosts:
    be1.internal.example.com

backend_ec2_2:
  hosts:
    be2.internal.example.com

backend_ec2_3:
  hosts:
    be3.internal.example.com
```

[Ansible v2.9.7]

Comment: please add sample inventory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command lists the groups defined in the inventory

```
ansible localhost -m debug -a 'var=groups.keys()' -i inventory/production/
```

Comment: This indeed works nicely, even for heavily nested groups.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the `jq` command to parse the json output from `ansible-inventory --list`, like this:

```
$ ansible-inventory -i hosts --list | jq .all.children
[
  "backend_ec2_1",
  "backend_ec2_2",
  "backend_ec2_3",
  "ungrouped",
  "webserver_1",
  "webserver_2"
]
```

Or if you want just bare names:

```
$ ansible-inventory -i hosts --list | jq -r '.all.children[]'
backend_ec2_1
backend_ec2_2
backend_ec2_3
ungrouped
webserver_1
webserver_2
```

Comment: Nice, I was going to suggest using `yq` yesterday, but was waiting on [this bug fix](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/issues/665) 

Comment: These don't work for me (with Ansible 2.10). It seems as if they only work for rather flat inventory structures.